# Show that a point a lies in the set S of sub sequential limits for the sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Let $a_n = (a_1^{(n)},\cdots,a_m^{(n)})$ be a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Show that a point $a = (a_1,\cdots,a_m)$ lies in the set $S$ of sub-sequential limits for the sequence $a_n$ if and only if for every $i = 1,\cdots,m$ the number $a_i$ lies in the set $S_i$ of sub-sequential limits for the sequence $a_i^{(n)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

This is a consequence of the fact that the sup norm $\Vert x \Vert_\infty= \sup\limits_i \vert x_i \vert$ is equivalent to the Euclidean norm $\Vert x \Vert_2=\sqrt{\sum_i \vert x_i \vert^2}$.

You can prove that $\Vert x \Vert_\infty \le \Vert x \Vert_2$. So if a sequence converges to a point according to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$, the projection of each coordinate converges to the projection of the limit.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: Some additional arguments added.